# Match everything except specific format

Tags: regex

i have some problem matching everything except a specific pattern. I post an example:

My string is:

```
test 1) test2 3) test3 22) test5 34)
```

What i need to select is everything except 1) 3) 22) 34)

I used this `(?!\d+\))`, but this pattern match only the numbers.

I mean the result is:  `test ) test2 ) test3 ) test5 )`.

Instead I would like to have this: `test test2 test3 test5`

How can I do to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have this: `test test2 test3 test5`

You need to use

```
\s*\d+\)
```

And replace with empty string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN9wH3/2)

- `\s*` - matches 0 or more whitespace symbols
- `\d+` - matches 1 or more digits
- `\)` - matches a literal `)`

Comment: In case of further issues, do not hesitate to drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below regexes will help you to grab the desired string.

```
(?!\d+\))\b\S+\b
```

or

```
\d+\)|(\S+)
```

or

```
\d+\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yG3eB1/1)